# Understanding bra-ket outer product infinite sum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators

I have an elementary question on clarifying the following expression:
$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |n+2\rangle \langle n| $
Can the term $|n+2\rangle \langle n|$ be observed as the outer product of the column and row vector, $e_{n+2} $ and $e_{n}$ resulting in an infinite dimensional matrix?

Answer (score 2):

Call $O = \sum_{n=0}^\infty|n+2\rangle \langle n |$. Then
$$
\langle i |O|j\rangle = \delta_{i,j+2}\,.
$$
So it can be seen as the matrix
$$
O_{ij} \equiv \langle i |O|j\rangle = \left(
\begin{matrix}
0 & \cdots &&0
\\0
\\1 &0&&\vdots
\\0&1&0
\\0&0&1&0
\\0&\cdots&0&\ddots
\end{matrix}
\right)_{ij}
$$